# Resizing CCLayer. Not scaling

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I have a `CCLayer`, that should be "unmasked" from top to bottom.

I implemented `GLScissor` pre-visit and post-visit to cut what is out of the layer bounds:

```
#pragma mark Clipping
-(void)visit {
    [self preVisit];
    [super visit];
    [self postVisit];
}
-(void)preVisit {
    if (!self.visible)
        return;

    glEnable(GL_SCISSOR_TEST);
    CGRect clipRect = [self boundingBox];
    CGPoint origin = [self convertToWorldSpaceAR:clipRect.origin];
    CGRect scissorRect = CGRectMake(origin.x - self.anchorPoint.x * clipRect.size.width, 768 - origin.y - self.anchorPoint.y * clipRect.size.height, clipRect.size.width, clipRect.size.height);

    scissorRect = CC_RECT_POINTS_TO_PIXELS(scissorRect);

    glScissor((GLint) scissorRect.origin.x, (GLint) scissorRect.origin.y,
          (GLint) scissorRect.size.width, (GLint) scissorRect.size.height);
}
-(void)postVisit {
    glDisable(GL_SCISSOR_TEST);
}
```

And I make the `CCLayer` grow by setting a contentSize of 1024x0 and using a scheduled call:

```
-(void) grow {
    float height = [self contentSize].height + 2;
    if (height >= 768){
        [self unschedule:@selector(grow)];
        height = 768;
    }
    [self setContentSize:CGSizeMake(1024, height)];
}
```

This works like a charm. The `CCLayer` grows in height steadily and it is unmasked perfectly. However, I can't use any of the easing functions since I'm not using any action.

Is there any action that resizes the `CCLayer` (not scaling) that would allow me to use easing functions or is there any other (better) way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best candidate is to use CCActionTween (formerly: CCPropertyAction) and wrap that in an ease action:

```
id tween = [CCActionTween actionWithDuration:5 key:"sizeHeight" from:1024 to:0];
id ease = [CCEaseInOut actionWithAction:tween];
[layer runAction:ease];
```

This will modify the property named `sizeHeight` of the layer. You can use that to adjust the contentSize, since you can't tween a C struct property like CGSize or CGPoint directly:

```
-(void) setSizeHeight:(float)height
{
    self.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.contentSize.width, height);
}
```